# import all categories from ebay category list

Tags: ebay-api

I'm using ebays developer program to list ebays category list, what I would like to do is import this list using ebays API calls, my question is, I am re-inventing the wheel to create a list of insert statements to import all categories or is there already an sql list created somewhere? in cpanel you just go to the database and choose export so I'm wondering if ebay has this tucked away somewhere?

Answer (score -1):

You can easily import all eBay category via eBay API.

eBay is proving API **GetCategories**, using that you can get categories of your eBay side.

Ex :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetCategoriesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>ABC...123</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
</GetCategoriesRequest>
```

**eBay is proving Site ID ,Dev ID ,Cert Id,Token, using this parameter you can request in eBay.It will give you all categories in response.**

You can find eBay API detail description from below link.

http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/GetCategories.html#Samples

Comment: Ive looked at this, comes back with an error, I don't know if that is ebays developer side or not because I made a new token to run the above but came back with error plus the above does not give me name and cat_id on its own,

Comment: Not giving me what I need, seems there are child cats etc so how many loops is that? only getting top level cats with this




    foreach($xml->CategoryArray->Category as $category) 
    {
       $categoryName = (string) $category->CategoryName;
       $catid = (string) $category->CategoryID;
       echo $categoryName . " " . $catid . " <br>\n";  
    }